# Benefit of using Android encryption if my files are in sdcard?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption

I tried using `Settings > Security > Encryption` but found out it did not encrypt the sdcard.

My question now is, what kind of data is being protected by Android's built in encryption ? Is there any benefit to it if I am storing personal files to sdcard anyway?